# difference between 2 timestamp data with nanoseconds in hive

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql, sql-timestamp

I have 2 columns with timestamp data upto nanoseconds which is coming from a transaction log file. I want to find the difference in time upto nanoseconds. I have tried to directly subtract the columns data by converting them into timestamp but getting multiple errors while doing so. Is there any way to do it in Hive.

`Request_Time                        Response_Time
2018-11-08 12:24:24.123456345       2018-11-09 12:24:24.123556567
2018-11-08 23:59:59.234123678       2018-11-09 00:00:00.342567456
2018-11-08 12:24:24.678345345       2018-11-09 01:02:03.688456678
2018-11-08 12:24:24.789456234       2018-11-08 12:24:24.799455567`

I want to find the difference which is (Response_Time - Request_Time).
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: @GaurangShah: No matching method for class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFOPMinus with (timestamp, timestamp) . Also i don't know, even if there is some method for this, what will be the return value.Will it be seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds etc.

Comment: share your code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a direct method to do this,

What you can do is convert the timestamp to unix timestamp and then get the difference, However that will give you difference till seconds only, not till nanoseconds.

However, following will.

```
SELECT (unix_timestamp("2018-11-09 12:24:25.123556567")+cast(split("2018-11-09 12:24:25.123556568","\\.")[1]*0.0000000010 as decimal (12, 12)))
-
(unix_timestamp("2018-11-09 12:24:25.123556567")+cast(split("2018-11-09 12:24:25.123556567","\\.")[1]*0.0000000010 as decimal (12, 12)) )
from temp.test_time
```

The difference will be in following format

> unix_timestamp.nano_seconds

For table,

```
SELECT *,(unix_timestamp(time1)+cast(split(time1,"\\.")[1]*0.0000000010 as decimal (12, 12))) - 
(unix_timestamp(time)+cast(split(time,"\\.")[1]*0.0000000010 as decimal (12, 12)))
from temp.test_time
```